# Как убрать кнопку в DataGrid "выбрать всё"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто подскажет как она называется эта кнопка? Или как убрать её?

Answer (score 0):

Установите свойство `HeadersVisibility` в значение `Column` (по умолчанию там `All`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В нынешней версии (2019) это свойство называется RowHeadersVisible, находится на вкладке "Внешний вид".

Comment: В вопросе говорится про `WPF`, вы же привели ответ для `WinForms`.